# Apple Watch Prevent from being inActive when User wrist down

Tags: swift, swiftui, apple-watch, watchos

I want the specific behaviour from my apple watch, i am developing a Fitness app in apple watch.

Problem:

- When user will be on **some specific screen** (e.g. Download ODRs from firebase). user faces issue that when user slightly down their wrist and Screen goes deem and Refresh rate goes to 1 FPS. Client has special requirement that Screen should not go to Sleep When that particular downloading process is running.

References(Example):

- I tried to find solution everywhere and found some questions also over StackOverflow about this but there also saying not possible so i still haven't found anything related to this but i have found one **example** that is doing this behaviour is **Apple watch app Mindfulness**. When user runs this app and start the session as much time user will be on that screen watch will not go to inactive state no matter user raise the hand or lower down the hand.

i want to implement that same behaviour in my app. Client wants no mater what ever it takes make it work. **(No issues with battery life** also or **Computation).** i may need to implement this kind of behaviour in other screens as well.

- I have tried one solution that is to **Turn on auto Rotate** so that when user slightly turns their wrist it will rotate instead of going to Sleep or inactive state, but it isn't the solution and looks like something weird behaviour
- I have also tried **TimelineView()** but it will be **useful once watch goes to inactive** state and also it is useful when doing computations but if i have to update UI it will only do it at 1FPS in inactive state no matter how frequent your data is updating.

Thanks in advance :)